# Redirecting Output to Event Log

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a solution to minimize some code while writing to the event log.  From my research, the cmdlets that deal with the event log do not accept input from the pipeline (I think they should at least accept a string but that is a different topic).  This my solution at the moment:

```
Write-EventLog -LogName POSH_Tools -Source XXX -EventId 155 -Message "User has chosen to provide separate creditials ($($Creds.username))to authenicate to $Target."
New-PSDrive -Name ForenTemp -Root \\$Target\$WindowsPath -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $creds -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
Write-EventLog -LogName POSH_Tools -Source XXX -EventId 155 -Message ""
```

That gets the job done but I just don't like how it is formatted.  I mean I could wrap the `Write-EventLog` into a function to accept from the pipeline, but I just want to know if there is anything native to POSH that could this for me. Like something like this:

```
Write-EventLog blah blah | Write-CommandToEventLog $_ blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to a "native" method of pipelining output into the eventlog would be running `Write-EventLog` in a `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
... | ForEach-Object { Write-EventLog -Message $_ ... }
```

Otherwise you'll have to wrap `Write-EventLog` in a custom function:

```
function Out-EventLog {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string]$Message,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ...)]
    [string]$LogName = 'Application',
    ...
  )

  Process {
    Write-Eventlog -LogName $LogName -Message $Message ...
  }
}
```

Comment: That is what I thought.  Maybe I'll submit a feature request to the Dev team to let the message parameter accept from the pipeline. Thanks for the input and format editing.